# ActiveMQ Artemis - connect to slave instance's web console

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have configured the ActiveMQ Artemis master and slave instances.
In previous releases, it was possible to configure remote access to a slave instance from the web console of the master instance.

How can I do the same with ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0?
I don't see "Connect" in the navigation bar.
It would be better to configure this feature in the configuration files (etc/).

Comment: What do you mean by, "It would be better to configure this feature in the configuration files (etc/)"?

Comment: I would prefer such a connection to be set up via configuration files. Updating such a machine would be limited to copying files.

Comment: As noted in Domenico's answer, the availability of the "Connect" tab *is* controlled via configuration files. I believe the proxy was removed by default for security reasons. To be clear, the option to simply point your browser directly to the slave is always available. That should be at least as simple as configuring the proxy connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis allows connecting to a remote instance through the hawtio proxy disabled by default since ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16. To enable the hawtio proxy you should set to false the `hawtio.disableProxy` property in `artemis.profile` file, see [hawtio configuration properties](https://hawt.io/docs/configuration/#configuration-properties) for further details.

Enabling the hawtio proxy makes the `Connect` tab available:

[image]

Comment: Tested. Works as expected.

Comment: And don't forget, depending on the hawtio version to set  hawtio.Allowlist (>= 2.10.1) or hawtio.Whitelist <=2.10.0)